# Codeigniter Error 403 when removing index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I am not sure where the error is coming from but when I access `subdomain.domain.com` the website loads, when I got to `subdomain.domain.com/dashboard/`the website also loads, but when I click a link on this webpage which should go to `subdomain.domain.com/system/patients` it is giving me an error 403 but when I manually type in `subdomain.domain.com/index.php/system/patients` the webpage is working fine.

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Edit: Below are the error logs from Apache

> [Tue May 15 13:30:39.765075 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 5460:tid 1984] [client ::1:57447] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/mdcsoftware/system/patients
>   [Tue May 15 13:30:42.085656 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 5460:tid 1984] [client ::1:57447] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/mdcsoftware/system/patients
>   [Tue May 15 13:30:43.826818 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 5460:tid 1984] [client ::1:57447] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/mdcsoftware/system/patients
>   [Tue May 15 13:32:12.990937 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 5460:tid 1984] [client ::1:57469] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/mdcsoftware/system/patients
>   [Tue May 15 13:32:14.865024 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 5460:tid 1984] [client ::1:57469] AH01630: client denied by server configuration:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/mdcsoftware/system/patients

Comment: _"Anyone knows how to fix this issue?"_ <- your Apache error log probably knows

Comment: have u set your base_url

Comment: @pradeep yes it is

Comment: Also check to make sure you don't have a real directory or file `system/patients`. If that exists, the `RewriteRule` will not apply

Comment: set $config['index_page'] = ''; it should be blank

Comment: @pradeep it is blank

Comment: @Phil what do you mean by i should not have a real directory or file? I have application->controllers->System->Patients.php

Comment: I mean, in your server's filesystem, relative to `index.php`, do you have a real file or directory path named `system/patients/` or even `system/patients.*`, eg `system/patients.php`. Also, **have you looked in your Apache error log yet?**

Comment: ok make sure your .htaccess file is in project folder parallel to application folder, and also have loaded url helper

Comment: To start with, make sure that you have the module mod_rewrite enabled in Apache

Comment: @Phil yes, we do have that directory path `system/patients.php`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes it is enabled

Comment: @pradeepl the .htacess is located there, and the url is part of the autoload.

Comment: Does your Apache config (root or VirtualHost) happen to have `Options MultiViews` by any chance? Try adding `Options -Multiviews` to the top of your `.htaccess` file. Also **HOW ABOUT THAT ERROR LOG?**

Comment: @Phil as per apache error logs AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Comment: Have you tried `Options -MultiViews` yet? There's usually a lot more to an error log entry than that. What **exactly** is the request that caused that error? You may also need to look in the access log

Comment: @Phil sorry had to replicate the issue in localhost here are the complete error logs, updated the question to include the error logs.

I have also tried putting Options -MultiViews on line 1 of my ,htacess and I am still receiving the same error

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you don't have a directory at `C:/xampp/htdocs/mdcsoftware/system/patients`? It really does look like the request is trying to access the index of that directory and indexes are disabled, thus the 403 response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171044/discussion-between-beldion-and-phil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing the folder name from "system" to "clinic". I think the word "system" is a reserved word in Codeigniter 3.1.8, though I don't have any documentation to back this up. Thank you to everyone who tried helping me.

Comment: nice. didnt know this. :D

Answer (score -1):

if you have error with your index.php . please try the below code once it may help you.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Good advice to include the `QSA` flag but I doubt this is OP's problem